# Is this possible to force execution of .click() for all elements, even those that are underneath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click, jquery-events

Consider [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/9cFTG/2/):

HTML:

```
<div class='a'>a</div>
<div class='b'>b</div>
<div id='log'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.a, .b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
}
.a {
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
.b {
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('*').click(function(e) {
    log(this.nodeName + ' ' + this.className);
});

function log(s) {
    $('#log').append(s + '<br />');
}
```

If the intersection is clicked, `.click()` for `.a` is not called.

Is there any built-in method to force the execution of `click()` for all elements, and not only the top one and its parents, or I must implement this myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the behavior you are observing is correct. When clicking the topmost element the one beneath won't get a click event despite it looks it is in the "clicked" area. As a workaround you can manually trigger it's click event:
`$('.a').click()`.

Calling `click` without arguments is equivalent to `trigger('click')` which raises the specified event. You can find more info in the [trigger help topic](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: I was hoping to find a built-in solution (I thought I saw it somewhere, but can't remember where). Thanks anyway !